# Why this randomization method gives skewed results?

Tags: javascript, random

I'm using two different randomization methods, while one gives results whose variance is what I expect, the other method gives results which are skewed and in a very consistent way too.

The methods:

```
function randomA() {
    var raw = Number((Math.random()+'').substr(2));
    return raw % NUM_OF_POSSIBLES;
}

function randomB() {
    var raw = Math.round(Math.random()*10000);
    return raw % NUM_OF_POSSIBLES;
}
```

When `NUM_OF_POSSIBLES = 2` the first method (`randomA()`) results in a rather consistent number of zeros (64%) and 36% of 1s. While `radnomB()` does pretty much 50/50.
If `NUM_OF_POSSIBLES = 5` the first method again is skewed in a pretty consistent way:
0: 10%, 1: 23%, 2: 22%, 3: 22%, 4: 23%, while the second one gives around 20% to each result.

You can find the full code with multiple tests here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M5pZG/)

Why is the first method skewed, and also why is the skewing consistent?

Comment: Something is making me think that it's because you're increasing the size of the number before the modulous but for the life of me I can't think why. It could be to do with how `Number()` formats the output. Though. Is it consistent between the two without the `*10000`?

Comment: @Askanison4 I wish I could agree (or retort!) but I am puzzled myself,  people here in the office are kind of driven crazy with this :D

Comment: @Askanison4 if I don't multiply I can't modulous, but if I multiply by only a 100 the results remain the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure, but my guess is that it has to do with the rounding mode used when JavaScript formats a number as a string. In the first case, your result depends on the choice of last digit, which is sensitive to this rounding. If it's biased toward even numbers, that would explain your results. (In the case of `NUM_OF_POSSIBLES == 5`, it would be because of a deficit of 5s as the last digit.) In the second routine, the result depends on an intermediate digit of the string representation, which is pretty much isolated from that influence.

You might have better results by chopping off the last digit or two in the first routine.

**EDIT** I just confirmed experimentally that if the first routine is changed to chop off the last digit:

```
function randomA() {
    var raw = String(Math.random());
    raw = raw.substring(2, raw.length-1);
    return raw % NUM_OF_POSSIBLES;
}
```

then the bias appears to be gone when `NUM_OF_POSSIBLES == 2` or `5`.

Comment: Javascript does in fact bias towards even numbers. [MDN Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random): "numbers in JavaScript are IEEE 754 floating point numbers with round-to-nearest-even behavior"

Comment: Yeah, has to be something to do with the rounding

Comment: Chopping off the last digits in the first method works well, but I'm not sure how this explains the consistency of the results - with any number of `NUM_OF_POSSIBLES`

Comment: @MeLight - The bias explains the results for 2 and 5. I don't see a bias for many other values of `NUM_OF_POSSIBLES` (3 or 7, for instance). I suspect that values of `NUM_OF_POSSIBLES` that have a factor of 2 or 5 will show a bias for `randomA` because of the bias in how JavaScript generates the last digit of the representation.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the reason of why randomA is working in such way is because java script uses [floating poing numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) with 52+1 Digits (table under Basic formats chapter). So after random function returns too big value it is rounded, for example

```
Math.pow(2, 54) +1 
//18014398509481984
Math.pow(2, 54)  
//18014398509481984
Math.pow(2, 54)  -1
//18014398509481984
```

all return the same value wich is divided by 2 (because of rounding).

for more understanding you can play and see how it looks in biniry format , examples :

```
parseInt(Math.pow(2, 54) - 2).toString(2)
//"111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110"
parseInt(Math.pow(2, 54) - 3).toString(2)
//"111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100"
parseInt(Math.pow(2, 54) ).toString(2)
//"1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
parseInt(Math.pow(2, 54) -1).toString(2)
//"1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

Answer (score 1):

You get the bias because the results of `Math.random()` aren't always of the same length, so for example `0.123` and `0.1235` count towards the "ones" heap.

You could think that it'd be corrected if you even out the lengths with trailing zeroes, but that also won't be correct, because `0.123` could be a rounded `0.122999999999`.

The real error of the first method is relying on the least significant digit of an imprecise fraction (both %2 and %5 are only affected by the last digit), which had suffered rounding errors when converted from binary to decimal for presentation.

The original, binary form of the fraction is probably uniformly distributed, but there's no way of reading it in Javascript.

Now, if someone would explain the distribution of trailing digits of a rounded decimal fraction...